# How to redirect Iframe to another URL php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, iframe

I have parent page index.php and inside it i have iframe like below

```
<div id="main-content1" style="position:absolute;float:none;top:80px;margin-left:170px;width: 830px;">
            <iframe onload="IfarmeOnload();"  style="display:block; margin-left:none;  margin-right:none; width: 100%; height: 100%;" src="<?php echo $home; ?>" id="rightMenu" name="rightMenu"   frameborder="0"></iframe>

        </div>
```

when i click on  the link that located in Parent window i want to redirect iframe content to according to that URL.

Then once Iframe loaded sucessfully i want redirect whole index.php page only once

EDIT

i tried this

```
echo "<script> document.getElementById('rightMenu').contentWindow.location='http://www.google.lk'</script>";
```

but this is redirecting to google.lk to not loading inside the ifamme

Comment: iframes are dated there are much better solutions such as ajax

Comment: yes true but this moment i have no options

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Give your `iframe` a name:

```
<iframe name="myIframeName"></iframe>
```

Reference your `iframe` in desired hyperlinks with the `target` attribute:

```
<a href="/path/to/page.php" target="myIframeName"></a>
```

Comment: this is ok once redirect the iframe i want to refresh my parent window also without changing ifame contnet

Comment: The state of the iframe will not be retained once its parent window has been reloaded. Your only option at that point would be to default the source of the iframe once the parent window has been reloaded.

Comment: Another option might be to use DOM manipulation and get rid of the iframe altogether.

Comment: is there any way to refresh only parent object instead of ifame

Comment: No. However, if you take my suggestion regarding DOM manipulation you will eliminate the complexity and overhead associated with several round trips to the server, which ultimately creates a segmented and choppy experience for the end-user.

Answer (score 1):

I do not seat by the computer but I think
You need something like that
Document.getElementById("rightMenu").location.href

Or try this one 
iframeobj.src = url

Or the same code that you wrote but without contentwindow

Comment: this is ok once redirect the iframe i want to refresh my parent window also without changing ifame contnet –